# Extract String Elements from a List According to the Text They Contain with Python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to extract certain lines from a text file using Python and import them into a new text file I created. I used code like below for this but I got an **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'** and I'm stuck here.

If I need to explain what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to add the lines in the text file to a list and extract the lines that contain the text "Name" or "DefaultText" from that list. But I think I followed the wrong method.

I have left below a similar text file from which I am trying to extract the texts. I would be very grateful if you can help me how to do this extraction process.

This is the Python code I tried to use:

```
file = open("blabla.txt","r")
array = []
array.append(file.readlines())
file.close()
filesecond = open("output.txt","w")
for i in range(len(array)):
    boolean1 = array[i].find("\"Name\"")
    boolean2 = array[i].find("\"DefaultText\"")
    if boolean1 == True:
        filesecond.write(array[i])
    if boolean2 == True:
        filesecond.write(array[i])
    
filesecond.close()
```

And this is the example file I tried to extract texts from it:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G1vga13SU0yG2pd_TGDI02nCZL0aKrOz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Change to `array.extend(file.readlines())`. Then you will actually have a list of lines, not a singleton list containing another list.

Comment: Btw, `str.find` does not return a boolean, but the index where the found pattern was found. When not found, it returns `-1`

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems with your code.
[doing this will create list inside list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skHwy.png)

like @user2390182 suggested use extend method

also use `with open('blabla.txt', 'r') as rf:` on which you don't have to close.

references for `with open('blabla.txt', 'r') as rf:` method: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/with-open-in-python-with-statement-syntax-example/

```
lines = []

with open(r"blabla.txt", 'r') as rf:
    lines = rf.readlines()

with open('output.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in lines:
        if "\"Name\"" in line or "\"DefaultText\"" in line:
            wf.write(line)
            wf.write('\n')
```

Comment: When I tried to run this code for the main file, Python gave me this error in line 4:
"UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3334: character maps to <undefined>"

Comment: @refik Adding `encoding="utf8` inside with open function should work like`with open(r"blabla.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8) as rf:` and  `with open('output.txt', 'w',encoding="utf8) as wf:`